# Sum Index/Match based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to lookup and sum values based on multiple criteria. In the attached image I have each Project's Line Item Expense Value. What I want to be able to do is to combine these values. So if the criteria was Project A, Project B, Project C, and Line item Expense 1 the output should be $115.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Will there ever be duplicate Line Item Expenses that need to be added?

Comment: No duplicates. There will be a significant amount of line items and projects if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the Line Item Expenses are unique then use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDEX($C$4:$E$9,MATCH(C12,$B$4:$B$9,0),0),$C$3:$E$3,$B$12:$B$14))
```

The INDEX return an array of the values on the line desired.  Then the SUMPRODUCT will iterate the criteria and run 3 different SUMIF and add the returns.

[image]

Comment: Aha! Thanks for that great answer, I was going to jump down the `SUMPRODUCT()` rabbit hole and you've saved me from doing so. Cheers! :D